How to actually do calculations with the quantum-mechanical Heisenberg model?
The Heisenberg Hamiltonian in its simplest form is
$$\hat{H}= \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i,j} \hat{S}_i \cdot \hat{S}_j.$$
Normally, $\hat{S}$ is assumed to be a classical vector and from this Hamiltonian the Ising model or the XY-Model is derived to explain phase transitions and critical phenomena.
But how do you actually use this Hamiltonian if $\hat{S}$ is a quantum mechanical spin and only $\hat{S}^z$ and $\hat{S}^2$ are defined? Do you only use $\hat{S}^z_i$ and $\hat{S}^z_j$ in this case?
At this point in books the reader is often referred to the Pauli matrices before just going into the classical case and without stating in which way the Pauli matrices are actually used here.

If there is need to take care of the x and y components, the usual trick is to use the ladder operators to access them.

If I recall correctly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation
